# Python EOF error when reading input

Tags: python

```
n = input()
dum = input()
d = {}
for i in range(0,n+1):
    x = raw_input()
    x = x.split(" ")
    d[int(x[0])] = int(x[1])

array = d.keys()

for key in d.keys():
    if(d[key]!=0):
        if(d[key] not in d.keys()):
            for i in d.keys():
                for j in d.keys():
                    if(i!=j and i!=key and j!=key):
                        if(i+j==d[key]):
                            # print str(i)+"-"+str(j)
                            if(i in array):

                                array.remove(i)
                            if(j in array):
                                # print j
                                array.remove(j)
        else:
            # print d[key]
            array.remove(d[key])
print array[0]
```

When I execute this Python code I am getting "EOF error when reading input".

Can you please help? I am running Python 2.7.5

Error Traceback

```
Traceback (most recent call last):
File "prog.py", line 1, in <module>
EOFError: EOF when reading a line
```

Comment: I am getting IndexError: list index out of range

Comment: Please include the full error traceback.

Comment: If array is empty, you would get that. But I am unable to execute the code because of EOF error.

Comment: @Forge I have included the error traceback

Comment: `5`
`6`
`11 21`
`21 0`
`31 52`
`41 61`
`61 0`

Answer (score 4):

I can't seem to reproduce this error although using the same input as you did. Maybe you have a `newline` character before the input you have specified?
Try running this code using `python prog.py` in your terminal.

`EOF error` is expected if no data is given when calling `input` or `raw_input` as explained in the [documentation](https://docs.python.org/2/library/exceptions.html#exceptions.EOFError).

Also, it's advisable to use `raw_input` and not `input` when getting input from the user on `python 2`, it's not going to fix your error though.

Answer (score 2):

In Python 2, `raw_input()` returns a string, and `input()` tries to run the input as a Python expression. So, changing your first line to something like this should work.

```
n = int(raw_input())
```

According to the official [documentation](https://docs.python.org/2/library/functions.html#input)

> Equivalent to eval(raw_input(prompt)).
>
> This function does not catch user errors. If the input is not
>   syntactically valid, a SyntaxError will be raised. Other exceptions
>   may be raised if there is an error during evaluation.

Answer (score 0):

This:

```
for i in range(0,n+1):
```

does `n+1` number of iterations, yet your input file:

```
5
6
11 21
21 0
31 52
41 61
61 0
```

Only has `n` number of lines remaining when that loop is about to start. Upon attempting to read a `n+1`th line, you'll get an EOFError as there are no more lines.

Answer (score 0):

I was really confused by this problem as well, and I couldn't find the direct answer on other resources.

However, what the issue was for me was I am using PyCharm and **my configurations for my .py file were wrong**. Basically, I had it looking for an external file to source input from instead of the console.

I had to change these configurations by unchecking the *"emulate terminal in output console"* box in the picture below and then it worked perfectly.

[image]