# a,b= input().split() on python 2

Tags: python

wish I can get some help!

When i was solving questions online with python2, the book told me that when you want to receive two inputs at the same time, it told me to use the code:

`a,b=input().split()`

but whenever I typed this code it told me that EOF error has showed.

So I tried: `a,b= raw_input().split()`

but same EOF problem pops up can I get some explanations about why it doesn't work?

thanks

Comment: Are you running this from an IDE ?

Comment: Welcome to [Stack Overflow!](https://stackoverflow.com) Please take the [tour](https://stackoverflow.com/tour), have a look around, and read [How do I ask a good question?](https://stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-ask) and provide a [Minimal, Complete, and Verifiable example](https://stackoverflow.com/help/mcve).

Comment: See [this answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/35670780/550094).

Comment: Your second piece of code `a,b= raw_input().split()` works perfectly under Python 2, and can't produce an EOF exception. Also, if you're currently learning Python, you should really start with Python 3.

Answer (score 1):

try this:

```
a,b=input(),input()
```

if you want to use split() then try it like

```
word1,word2=input().split()
```

you must need to enter the word without using "enter" just use "space" in between those two words

like

```
'first second'
```

it will assign 
word1='first'
word2='second'

Answer (score 0):

Instead of running the code in Python live interpreter save the code in a file and execute that file.

Comment: Since, I don't know the difference is it really that different?

Comment: There are some codes that can't be executed on python live interpreter? but can be run on file based?

Comment: This would make no difference. The problem lies in the use of `input` where `raw_input` should have been used, nothing else.

Comment: @ThierryLathuille You can reproduce the EOF exception in Python live interpreter

Answer (score -1):

This is because raw_input or input returns only 1 value. However, assignment like `a,b = something` would require 2 values in the right hand side.

One way to do this can be:

```
def myfun():
    ip = raw_input("Enter A & B : ")
    a, b = ip.split()[0], ip.split()[1]
    print a
    print b
```

**Output:**

```
>> myfun()
Enter A & B : 10 20
10
20
```

Here, the value returned by raw_input method is stored as a string, on which the split operation can be performed.