# I'm getting EOF error and unable to resolve it

Tags: python-3.x

I'm trying to solve https://practice.geeksforgeeks.org/contest-problem/sahil-love-good-scorer/0/ problem and getting this below error although this code runs well on other IDE's

```
Runtime Error:
Runtime ErrorTraceback (most recent call last):
  File "/home/6571cce4dcc6723ee2dba6c01da8240c.py", line 3, in <module>
    m=list(map(int,input().split()))  
EOFError: EOF when reading a line
```

Here is my code:

```
n=int(input())
while n!=0:
m=list(map(int,input().split()))  

l1=list(map(int,input().split()))

l2=list(map(int,input().split()))
s1=sum(l1)
s2=sum(l2)

if s1>s2:
    print('C1')
else:
    print('C2')
```

What mistake am I doing please can anyone help.

Answer (score 0):

It appears you are using python 2. If so, this should work:

```
n = int(raw_input("enter n: "))
while n != 0:
    m = list(map(int, raw_input("enter m : ").split()))
    l1 = list(map(int, raw_input("enter l1: ").split()))
    l2 = list(map(int, raw_input("enter l2: ").split()))
    s1 = sum(l1)
    s2 = sum(l2)
    if s1>s2:
        print('c1')
    else:
        print('c2')
```

You may also find this answer useful: [Python EOF error when reading input](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/35668520/python-eof-error-when-reading-input)

I was however not able to reproduce the error using python 3.6.